# Civi Upgrade fail - "Could not delete Payment Processor Type"

Tags: upgrade

I'm on Drupal 7.67 and using IATS extension 1.7.0, While attempting to upgrade Civi from 15.17.4 to 5.21.0 the upgrade script gave me "API error: Could not delete payment processor type"
My search of Stack Exchange questions found two that seemed similar to my difficulty. However, corrective actions seemed to go in a couple of different directions and involved the Civicrm tables "civicrm_payment_processor_type" and "civicrm_managed".
In the Civicrm_managed table I found three "payment processor types. I'm wondering if I deleted those three payment processor types and than ran the upgrade process again, would this result in a clean upgrade. (I exported the entire "civicrm_managed" table so I could reconstruct those deleted entities if needed.)
However, I have one other possible option. Can I disable the IATS integration module, then run upgrade and renable the module when (and if the upgrade suceeds)?

Comment: You could also try a third option of applying the patch before doing upgrade: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16149/files. I assume the other stackexchange post you mean is this one: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34152/upgrade-fails-with-civicrm-api3-exception-api-error-could-not-delete-payment/34153#34153